How OpenCL set up the memory buffer between the Integrated dev and CPU cores?
The external device usually has their own separate memory, which requires the DMA memory region between the device and CPU to copy data from/to system DRAM to devices's internal DRAM.
Therefore, I believe OpenCL needs DMA setup for those regions. Also based on How OpenCL memory transfer functions work?, it seems that OpenCL sets up DMA buffer for data transfer.
My question is what happens for the integrated devices such as MaliGPU in SoC that shares the DRAM together with the CPU cores. I initially thought that it still also needs DMA memory region to communicate between the integrated device and CPUs for coherency purposes (even though the integrated GPU can access any memory region..)
So I patched dma_alloc_attrs function (which should be called by all DMA relevant APIs e.g., dma_alloc_coherent) in linux kernel to print out messages whenever the DMA region is set by some driver. However, when I run openCL application on Mali GPU, it never prints out the kernel message (Checked by dmesg). I am not sure whether it is because...

Still the DMA is utilized but the regions are usually cached and not frequently allocated at runtime because it utilize pre-allocated DMA regions

The opencl utilizes different dma allocation function, probably custom function or other kernel APIs..


Would anyone knows details of opencl implementations please answer my questions!

OpenCL for the case CPU+iGPU can set up / malloc memory only on the host side with CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, and share this pointer with the iGPU. Because CPU+iGPU use the same unified memory, it is not necessary to copy any data between host and device, and both have direct access.

Thanks for the reply! However recent processor has IOMMU to prevent the devices (even including integrated GPU) from accessing any system memory. Considering this environment, I believe the DMA relevant API should be invoked to generate the address space that can be accessed from both GPU and CPU. NO?

No. Mali GPU has it's own MMU, which is managed by the Mali kernel driver. It can map and access arbitrary memory/ It requires kernel driver to pin the pages to stop them being moved/paged, but there is no need for a heavy-weight DMA allocation for GPU memory that is local to a single process.
